# Select con 2 valores

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un select que relleno los datos con pluck, pero luego a la hora de mostrarlo en la vista no sé como concatenar más valores.

**Controlador**:

```
public function lista(){
    $productos = Productos::pluck('Codigo','Descripcion','PVP','id')->prepend('selecciona'); 
    return view ('Productos.NuevoProducto2',compact('productos'));
}
```

**Vista**:

```
{!! Form::select( 'producto',$productos,null,['id'=>'producto', 'data-live-search'=>'true']) !!}
```

Gracias un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que necesitas? ¿Añadir más valores al select además de los productos?

Comment: Lo que necesito es por ejemplo en esos productos estan el nombre, descripcion y producto, lo que quiero es que con un select me pille el nombre y que luego al seleccionarlo me ponga en un input box el valor del precio, me entiendes ahora mejor¿?